# How to calculate start and enddate and start every new row with the next start date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using this sql to calculate startdates and enddates:

```
WITH RankedProcess (ProcessOrder, ProcessDate, Seq) AS
(
  SELECT ProcessOrder, ProcessDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProcessDate) AS Seq
  From #Temp
)
SELECT  P1.ProcessOrder, P1.ProcessDate AS ProcessBegin, P2.ProcessDate AS ProcessEnd , P1.Seq , P2.Seq
FROM RankedProcess AS P1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RankedProcess AS P2
    ON P1.Seq = P2.Seq -1
```

And the Output look like this:

[image]

But i want it too look like this:

[image]

Differens rows that should not be there (red):

[image]

As an example: When the first row has

> 04.01.2016 - 11.01.2016

the next row should start with

> 18.01.2016 - 25.01.2016

The next row should have the `enddate` as the `startdate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since I can't see any reason why this wouldn't be logically correct, you can simply eliminate every even-numbered row:

```
WITH RankedProcess (ProcessOrder, ProcessDate, Seq) AS
(
  SELECT ProcessOrder, ProcessDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProcessDate) AS Seq
  From #Temp
)
SELECT  P1.ProcessOrder, P1.ProcessDate AS ProcessBegin, P2.ProcessDate AS ProcessEnd , P1.Seq , P2.Seq
FROM RankedProcess AS P1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RankedProcess AS P2
    ON P1.Seq = P2.Seq -1
WHERE P1.Seq % 2 = 1
```

Comment: thank you for your anwser. This was just an example. The real data would be like that: Every time an employee does a breaks he has to stamp his break time. and with that sql i can make a table with all his stamp times in a day

Comment: Ok, so is there some reason this answer doesn't work?  If so, you should edit your question to make your requirement more specific.